# Accessing the Mono.Cairo FontMatrix?

Tags: fonts, mono, osx-lion, cairo

I'm trying to write a font exporter for a project I am working on.  To work properly I need to get the proper width of each glyph.  This is complicated by the fact that the font bitmap is generated at a user specified scale (e.g. `CairoContet.SetFontSize(...)`)

When I try to access the `CairoContext.FontMatrix` to scale the extents, I get the following SIGSEGV:

```
Stacktrace:


Native stacktrace:

    0   mono                                0x000b6ea9 mono + 745129
    1   mono                                0x00006e0e mono + 24078
    2   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x949e259b _sigtramp + 43
    3   ???                                 0xffffffff 0x0 + 4294967295
    4   mono                                0x000b4e32 mono + 736818
    5   mono                                0x000b7ac4 mono + 748228
    6   mono                                0x000b8e18 mono + 753176
    7   mono                                0x00107a02 mono + 1075714
    8   ???                                 0x0035e2c1 0x0 + 3531457
    9   ???                                 0x003d9a18 0x0 + 4037144
    10  ???                                 0x0a20deb0 0x0 + 169926320

Debug info from gdb:

/tmp/mono-gdb-commands.ulVxAb:1: Error in sourced command file:
unable to debug self

=================================================================
Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
used by your application.
=================================================================
```

This is the code that triggers it, though in general ANY attempt to get the FontMatrix seems to cause the same error:

```
cr.FontMatrix.TransformDistance(ref xAdvance,ref yAdvance);
```

Is there an alternate/better way to scale the advances?  I cant do the math myself because
I don't know exactly what scale factor the SetFontSize set due to how it works (it sets the size of the em-quad).

Comment: I should add that this is on OSX Lion

Comment: Looking at the code, its my guess that cairo_font_set_matrix is expecting a pre-allocated block of memory to be passed in to put the matrix in, but its getting Null from the binding.